# ruby, tk lib. Output from getopenfile

Tags: arrays, ruby, tk-toolkit

I am trying to load multiple files via ruby/tk lib and put them into array:

```
def openFiles
return Tk.getOpenFile(  'title' => 'Select Files',
                        'multiple' => true, 
                        'defaultextension' => 'csv',
                        'filetypes' => "{{Comma Seperated Values} {.csv}} {TXT {.txt}} {All files {.*}}")
end
```

and then in code

```
filess = TkVariable.new()

button1 = TkButton.new(root){
text 'Open Files'
command (proc {filess.value = openFiles; puts filess; puts filess.class; puts filess.inspect})

}.grid(:column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'we')
```

The problem is that I can not manage to get the output as array and I do not know if it is possible or I will have to somehow parse the output. Hm? Please help. Thank you.

this is the output, when I click on the button:

```
C:\file1
C:\file2
TkVariable
#<TkVariable: v00000>
```

I think it should be: (for the array part)

```
['C:\file1','C:\file2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TkVariable` implements `#to_a`, which you can use to convert its `value` into the `Array` you want.

```
button1 = TkButton.new(root) {
  text 'Open Files'
  command (proc do
    filess.value = openFiles
    puts filess.to_a.class
    puts filess.to_a.inspect
  end)
}.grid(:column => 1, :row => 1, :sticky => 'we')
```

```
Array
["C:\file1", "C:\file2"]
```

Comment: [`TkVariable#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkVariable.html#method-i-to_a) is an alias for [`TkVariable#list`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkVariable.html#method-i-list). [`TkVariable#value=`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkVariable.html#method-i-value-3D) automatically converts (Ruby) arrays into Tcl's internal syntax, and `TkVariable#list` converts Tcl's internal syntax back into Ruby arrays.

Comment: So, `TkVariable.new(%w[a b\ c d]).value` is `"a {b c} d"`. Also, `TkVariable.new('a {b c} d').list` is `["a", "b c", "d"]`. These facts are useful when filenames contain spaces (for instance).

Comment: BTW, `TkVariable` isn't covered by Tk's [Commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm) documentation. Class [`TkVariable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkVariable.html) is defined only in the Ruby Tk wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7:

```rb
require 'tk'

def extract_filenames_as_ruby_array(file_list_string)
  ::TkVariable.new(file_list_string).list
end

def files_open
  descriptions = %w[
      Comma\ Separated\ Values
      Text\ Files
      All\ Files
      ]
  extensions = %w[  {.csv}  {.txt}  *  ]
  types = descriptions.zip(extensions).map {|d,e| "{#{d}} #{e}" }
  file_list_string = ::Tk.getOpenFile \
      filetypes: types,
      multiple: true,
      title: 'Select Files'
  extract_filenames_as_ruby_array file_list_string
end

def lambda_files_open
  @lambda_files_open ||= ::Kernel.lambda do
    files = files_open
    puts files
  end
end

def main
  b_button_1
  ::Tk.mainloop
end

# Tk objects:

def b_button_1
  @b_button_1 ||= begin
    b = ::Tk::Tile::Button.new root
    b.command lambda_files_open
    b.text 'Open Files'
    b.grid column: 1, row: 1, sticky: :we
  end
end

def root
  @root ||= ::TkRoot.new
end

main
```

For reference, `Tk.getOpenFile` is explained in the [Tk Commands](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm) and [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.5/libdoc/tk/rdoc/TkCore.html#method-i-getOpenFile) documentation.